# RavenDB: Indexing blog-post tags from multiple blogs

Tags: linq, mapreduce, ravendb, indexing

How do I created the appropriate `AbstractIndexCreationTask` for the following scenario?

For a scenario of **multiple blogs**, how do I get the tags from **specific blogs** and the **tag-count** for these?

Members of interest for data-structure stored in RavenDB:

```
public class BlogPost {
    public string BlogKey { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

The method I need to implement has the following signature:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> GetTagsByBlogs(string tag, params string[] blogKeys)
```

In normal LINQ I would write something like this:

```
var tags = from post in blogPosts
           from tag in post.Tags
           where blogKeys.Contains(post.BlogKey)
           group tag by tag into g
           select new {
               Tag = g.Key,
               Count = g.Count(),
           };
```

But neither `SelectMany` or `GroupBy` are supported in RavenDB. I've tried different combinations for a map-reduce solution, but I can't figure out how to do this since **the map and the reduce differ in data-structure**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to create a tag cloud is [described in the knowledge base](http://ravendb.net/kb/2/creating-a-tag-cloud) of RavenDB.

In your case, you have to include the `BlogKey` in the index, especially in the `group by` clause:

```cs
public class Tags_Count : AbstractIndexCreationTask<BlogPost, Tags_Count.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string BlogKey { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public Tags_Count()
    {
        Map = posts => from post in posts
                       from tag in post.Tags
                       select new { 
                           BlogKey = post.BlogKey,
                           Name = tag.ToString().ToLower(), 
                           Count = 1 
                       };
        Reduce = results => from tagCount in results
                            group tagCount by new { 
                                tagCount.BlogKey,  
                                tagCount.Name } into g
                            select new {
                                BlogKey = g.Key.BlogKey,
                                Name = g.Key.Name, 
                                Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count) 
                            };

        Sort(result => result.Count, SortOptions.Int); 
    }
}
```

Then query that index with the desired BlogKey:

```
var result = session.Query<Tags_Count.ReduceResult, Tags_Count>()
    .Where(x => x.BlogKey = myBlogKey)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .ToArray();
```

If you need to query for multiple blogs, you can try this query:

```
var tagsByBlogs = session.Query<Tags_Count.ReduceResult, Tags_Count>()
    .Where(x => x.BlogKey.In<string>(blogKeys))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .ToArray();
```

AFAIK that is as far as you can get with an index. You still have to aggregate the results on the client side as you did in your original question, except that you can skip the filtering on blogKeys:

```
var tags = from tag in tagsByBlogs
           group tag by Name into g
           select new {
               Tag = g.Key,
               Count = g.Count(),
           };
```

Comment: Then I have to `.ToList()` it and group again after calling a query to the index?

Comment: I prefer a complete answer than a comment, so that's great. The problem is that this doesn't solve the problem, since there is not `Where` needed, but a `In`-statement. That is, multiple `BlogKey`s, so I have to group it up again locally.

Comment: @SebNilsson I added the query for multiple blogKeys to my answer

Comment: It just returns a `IEnumerable<ReduceResult>`, which is just a long list of single tags and their count, and not the desired signature stated in the question. The final result should be the *unique* tags grouped with the total sum of their count from the different `BlogKey`s. Thanks for the effort, but so far this is just how far I got on my own.

Comment: Ok, sorry for wasting your and my time ;)

You can't get better results from an index. After querying you have to group them like you did in your original question, but you can skip the check for blogKey, because that was already done by the index.

Comment: Hehe, at least I didn't have to answer my own question :P Maybe summarizing it your above comment in the answer, and get correct question? At least as it looks now.

Comment: Done. Dunno if faceted search is doing a better job, I've never used that before.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [faceted search](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/faceted-search), you can specify the criteria at query time, like so:

```
var facetResults = s.Query<BlogPost>("BlogIndex") 
                        .Where(x => x.BlogKey == "1" || x.BlogKey == "5" ...) 
                        .ToFacets("facets/BlogFacets");
```

Then the grouping (and counts) is done on all the results that match the where clause.

**Update** You'll need an index that looks something like this:

```
from post in blogPosts
from tag in post.Tags 
select new 
{
    post.BlogKey
    Tag = tag     
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Not really getting how I would use it in my case. Could you add some additional code to clarify?

Comment: @SebNilsson see my update, that should be pretty much all the code you need

Comment: How does RavenDB understand where `facets/BlogFacets` comes from? Don't I need to do some groupings to get out the data I need? What I need returned is a `Dictionary<string, int>` with the 
`Tag`s as key and `Count` as value, from a varying number of `BlogKey`s. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: See step 1 from http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/faceted-search. You specify the doc name when you create the facet definition. Also the  return value from a ToFacet(..) should match what you need.

Comment: You don't need to do the grouping, the faceted query is doing that for you. Take a look at Step 3 from my previous link, it shows the output of a faceted query.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll check it out soon and see if I can transform the examples to be applicable for my problem.

Comment: Haven't had time to test it extensively, but as a first try I really can't quickly apply it to my problem.